# How do I swap values in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

[image: photo of my dataframe]

Hi, how can I switch every two values in a column with each other? What happened is the bowler pca values somehow got swapped in this dataframe, so I need to switch them around for all the games. ie Karachi Kings should have a bowler pca of -0.752828 and Quetta Gladiators should have the pca of -0.216844. I need to do this for every game, but I have no clue how to tackle this at all. Could someone help me out?

Comment: so you want to swap 1 with 2, 3 with 4, 5 with 6 and so on and so forth?

Comment: yeah exactly, or like if you see the match id, I want to switch the bowler PCA values for the same match id.  @clog14

Comment: you can do: `data.groupby('matchId')['bowler_pca'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[::-1])`

Comment: I don't think that worked, the pca values remained the same

Comment: this one:y = `x.groupby("a")["b"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::-1])` seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You could combine two lists (even and odds of the DataFrame column) to switch the values around:

```
df["bowler_PCA"] = [z for x, y in zip(df["bowler_PCA"].iloc[1::2], df["bowler_PCA"].iloc[::2]) for z in [x, y]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one here seems to work:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({"matchId": [1, 1, 2, 2], "bowler_PCA": [-1, 1, -2, 2]})


data["bowler_PCA"] = data.groupby("matchId")["bowler_PCA"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[::-1].values)
```

With output

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1 -1
2  2  2
3  2 -2
```